# How do I redirect example2.com to example.com

Tags: redirection

My website has 2 domain, example.com and example2.com.

**example.com/node/1** and **example2.com/node/1** are the same link.

**How do I redirect example2.com to example.com.**

When people open the linke example2.com/node/1, it will redirect to example.com/node/1

Comment: Is it only that one link you want to redirect? You can use the Redirect module to send visitors from the one page to the other. Or if you need to send all example2.com traffic to the corresponding example.com page, you can use a .htaccess directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method here, if you're using Apache, is to perform the redirect before it starts executing Drupal code. Place this in your site root's **.htaccess** file somewhere below the `RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]` line.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%{ENV:protossl}://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note: this will redirect *every request* so if you're just looking to redirect URLs with valid nodes it might not be the best solution here.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. I just give you the most straightforward (of course for me!) and simplest one.

In `hook_preprocess_html` use this code

```
THEME_preprocess_html(&$var){
      $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. request_uri();
      if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],'example2') !=false)   
           header("location:example.com/".request_uri());
}
```

I can't test this code right now, but this is the main idea:

Get current url components separately, the host (`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`) and what comes after it (`request_uri()`), if its `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` contains `example2` as a substring, then redirect the user to `example.com/request_uri()`

For redirection you can also use `drupal_goto` or anything else you want I just gave you the pure PHP.